# How to delete nested object from Knockout.js and at same time remove rendered template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, nested-class

I have following knockout.js mapping code:

```
    //JSON string
    var startData= {"Name":"SMT","Price":{"Value":22,"Currency":"EUR"}}";

    //convert json to model
    var viewModel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(startData);

    viewModel.deletePrice= function() {
        delete this.Price;
    };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then, I have following template that shows Price nested object on the page:

```
<script type="text/html" id="PriceTemplate">
//render Value and Currency properties from nested object Price
</script>
```

Then in my code, I bind Price object to the teplate PriceTemplate - and this all works OK.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'PriceTemplate', data: Price, templateOptions: { title: 'Prc'} }"></div>

    <a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { deletePrice() }">Delete Price</a>
```

The problem is this function `deletePrice()`. When it is called, it deletes the nested object Price, but the template is still rendered on the page with the initial data.

My question - how can I delete Price nested object and at same time remove rendered template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution ([using ViewModel knockout extension](http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/)):

```
var viewModel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(startData,{
    extend:{
        "{root}.Price":function(obj){
     return typeof(obj) == "object" ? ko.observable(obj) : ko.observable(null);    
                        }
    }
});

viewModel.deletePrice = function() {
    this.Price(null);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting the property from the object which is not an observable event. Is there any reason you can't set the value of price as an observable `this.Price(null)`? This would trigger the observable change necessary to update the UI.

Comment: just tried it. The problem is that Price is not observable but Object. Price properties (Value and Currency) are Observables. The error I get with your suggestion is "TypeError: this.Price is not a function"

Comment: Right, Price would have to be an observable for my originally proposed solution. If you don't want to make Price observable, another option would be to change the `deletePrice` method to set the Value and Currency observable properties to null and conditionally display your template similar to: `data-bind="if: Price.Value"`.